# I keep on getting: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, integer, nonetype

```
secInmin = 60

secInhour = 3600

secIndays = 86400

secondsInput = print(float(input('Input any number of seconds: ')))

Sc = secondsInput

*if (secondsInput >= secInmin):
    userSec = secondsInput / secInmin
    print(float('you have', userSec, 'minutes in your seconds'))

*if (secondsInput < secInmin):
    print(float('you have', secInmin, 'in your seconds'))*
```

This is my code. The starred portions are my trouble peices. The code goes through the first input and that works but the *if* is what keeps getting it stuck. this is the feedback.

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I honestly dont know what to do

i tried adding an or staement that would make *secInmin = 60* and *secondsInput = print(float(input('Input any number of seconds: ')))* the same thing unless the number being input was greater or less than 60. That didnt work either.

Comment: You should add a tag for what language this is, SO covers dozens of different languages not just (this one). Also the mod operator (% in C, C++, other C-likes) might be helpful here, `min = inputsecs / 60; sec = inputsecs % 60`

Comment: we cannot help you if you don't say which programming language you're using

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function doesn't return anything.  Thus, `secondsInput` contains `None`.  Separate that into two separate lines.

```
secondsInput = float(input('Input any number of seconds: '))
print(secondsInput)
```

Also, this code is wrong:

```
   print(float('you have', userSec, 'minutes in your seconds'))
```

You can't convert the string "you have" into a float.  Just write:

```
if secondsInput >= secInmin:
    userSec = secondsInput / secInmin
    print('you have', userSec, 'minutes in your seconds')

if secondsInput < secInmin:
    print('you have', secondsInput, 'in your seconds')
```

`print` knows how to convert floats for priting.